# Como passar valores do tipo Array no Postman

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, acl

Estou desenvolvendo uma API, e um dos módulos é o ACL(access control list) no Framework Laravel.

Cheguei a um problema que ainda não achei soluções plausiveis, que é como testar valores que recebem mais de uma parametro dentro ele.

No meu caso eu estou criando `Roles` e nessas `Roles`, no momento que eu for cria-las, preciso passar as `Permissions` que ela vai possuir, no postman. No cenário atual consigo apenas vincular a uma `Permission`.

Usei esses exemplos assim:

`campo [1, 2, 3] 
campo {1, 2, 3}
array[campo] 1,2,3`

Quero cadastrar `n` permissões para aquela nova Regra`.

[image: criando uma role com uma unica permission]

Comment: Chama o campo de `permissions[]`, com os colchetes e replique o campo quantas vezes desejar, semelhante à sintaxe do próprio PHP para adicionar o valor ao *array*.

Comment: dentro de cada `permissions[]` será um novo campo que vai ter um `id`, mais ou menos issO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passando um `campo[]` mas os valores para cada campo que precisa, no meu caso as permissões.

[image: solução]

Comment: Isso é uma resposta?

Comment: Sim. Passa o campo `Permissions[]` quantas vezes o campo precisar.

Answer (score 1):

Não basta enviar um array? A sua duvida é a respeito de sintaxe? Use algo como:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 49,
        "name": "Role 644",
        "label": "Role 453",
        "description": "Descrição da Role 258",
        "permissions": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "create_permission",
            "label": "Criar permissão",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "role_id": 49,
                "permission_id": 1
            }
        },{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "edit_permission",
            "label": "Editar permissão",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "role_id": 50,
                "permission_id": 2
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui.